# ruby script for cloudfront invalidation 2014-10-21

Tags: ruby, amazon-cloudfront, hashlib

I want equivalent of 
                     **`hashlib.sha256("Development").hexdigest()`** of python in ruby script

Kindly suggest as soon as possible.

I am using it for aws cloudfront.
Kindly suggest some ruby scripts for cloudfront invalidation on 2014-10-21.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [`Digest`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/digest/rdoc/Digest.html) and its subclasses:

```
require 'digest'
Digest::SHA256.hexdigest('Development')
=> "21b6a798321a49f75b9c3827fa3cfdb7efe2c4e05c3d13aefe1c825b9774a158"
```

Comment: How to use hashlib in ruby?
I am using sign-4 for 2014-10-21 for invalidation.
Can u suggest some examples for 2014-10-21 cloudfront invalidation

Comment: Sorry but I am not familiar with Cloudfront. BTW, what does that date has to do with it?

Comment: It is version of cloudfront api.

we have to send request to "2014-10-21/distribution/distribution ID/invalidation resource" to invalidate our distribution.


 http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/APIReference/CreateInvalidation.html

Comment: The problem is with Signature Version 4 Authentication. I was getting 403 response from http.